# Unable to change wallpaper using cronjob on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

My script -

```
#!/bin/sh

# export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

DIR="/home/umang/Downloads/Wallpapers"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/*.jpg | shuf -n1)
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://$PIC
```

cronjob file -

```
* * * * * /path/to/script/Wallpaper_Changer.sh
* * * * * date >> /path/to/logfile/CronTest.log
```

Wallpaper changes correctly via terminal and the dates are logged via cron.

I am running ubuntu 14.04, GNOME Shell 3.12.1.
Help me change wallpaper on gnome as well as unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all the solutions but none helped. The problem was, I was still unable to access the environment variables(DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS). So one could check if those are available first.

What worked for me is simply running the script in current shell environment. This can be done by running the script with a `.` as in cronjob file -

```
* * * * * . /path/to/script/Wallpaper_Changer.sh
```

More information : [Global environment variables in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464262/2008838) [Understanding Unix shells and environment variables](http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/understanding_unix_shells_and_environment_variables.htm)

Comment: It is not working for me. Please give me more details

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few questions that are similar to this on SO, a simple Google search yielded quite a few. There is this one:

[Run cronjob as user to change desktop background in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182468/run-cronjob-as-user-to-change-desktop-background-in-ubuntu)

This one:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/25489/wallpaper-change-crontab-jobs-not-working-after-upgrade-from-8-04-to-10-04

This one:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/403918/setting-cron-to-run-a-shell-script-random-wallpaper-from-a-webpage

And probably more. Hope one of these or others online help you out.